# Selenium - Locating an element based on 2 parts of a single element attribute

Tags: c#, selenium

I was wondering if it would be possible to find an element based on two parts of an attributes value.  For example, if I have an `id` like the following:

```
id="page_x0023_default-firstname_0_contractor"
```

How would I be able to locate an element by searching the `default-firstName` AND `contractor` of the id?

Comment: Do you know the values of these elements ahead of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//*[contains(@id, 'default-firstname')][contains(@id, 'contractor')]
```

or

```
//*[contains(@id, 'default-firstname') and contains(@id, 'contractor')]
```

or css:

```
[id*='part1'][id*='part2']
```